# C# MIDI Device Send CC Message to Reset Trigger

Tags: c#, midi

I have a LaunchPad MK3 Mini MIDI device that I'm looking to tie into a C# app I'm making, where pressing buttons will invoke a various functions within the app. After a bit of research, I landed on using the RtMidi.Core library (thru NuGet). And upon debugging, it appears that I'm able to fully listen to the device and react to events appropriately, and that's good.

I should also back up a bit as well. I'm quite inexperienced to using MIDI devices so a lot of the terminology and industry usage is a bit lost on me. But it's my understanding that a MIDI device can be modified so that the individual keys can be changed to perform a different MIDI event. In my case, I'm not using this for any musical purpose, so there is no need for Note/Piano type events. So I changed all the buttons to be Control Change, all of them with unique Channel/ControlNum combinations. It appears these CC buttons can be one of 3 "Pad Modes":

1. Momentary - Both KeyDown and KeyUp each will trigger a separate MIDI event
2. Toggle - Only KeyDown will trigger a MIDI event and each one will alternate between 0 and some specified non-zero value
3. Trigger - Only KeyDown will trigger a MIDI event, but it will always be the specified non-zero value

Now, as it pertains to my use cases. I'm looking to utilize the 'Trigger' Pad Mode type, as this will trigger some various code which will last a variable duration. My issue is, the MIDI device will change the LED keylight color to its ON color and it NEVER goes back to its initial state (as expected, tbh). So what I'm looking to do is after my 'certain function' is done executing, that it would 'reset' this trigger back to the initial state as its last course of action.

So, I create a ControlChangeMessage with the proper channel/control/value and send it to the MIDI device, but the LED color doesn't seem to change back to the original color. The ONLY thing that seems to reset its state is to unplug the USB power from the device and plug it back in.

For reference: The input and output device names I'm using are similar, but different, as indicated in the code below:

```cs
                foreach (var inputDeviceInfo in MidiDeviceManager.Default.InputDevices)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Opening {inputDeviceInfo.Name}");

                    if (inputDeviceInfo.Name == "MIDIIN2 (LPMiniMK3 MIDI) ")
                    {
                        var inputDevice = inputDeviceInfo.CreateDevice();
                        devices.Add(inputDevice);

                        inputDevice.ControlChange += ControlChangeHandler;
                        inputDevice.Open();
                    }
                }
                foreach (var outputDeviceInfo in MidiDeviceManager.Default.OutputDevices)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Opening {outputDeviceInfo.Name}");

                    if (outputDeviceInfo.Name == "MIDIOUT2 (LPMiniMK3 MIDI) ")
                    {
                        var outputDevice = outputDeviceInfo.CreateDevice();
                        devicesOut.Add(outputDevice);

                        outputDevice.Open();
                        //while (!outputDevice.IsOpen) { }

                        ControlChangeMessage ccMsg = new ControlChangeMessage(RtMidi.Core.Enums.Channel.Channel3, 0, 0);
                        outputDevice.Send(ccMsg);
                    }
                }
```

So from this, I'm really unsure why this wouldn't be working. Perhaps there is another MIDI library I could be using, or perhaps I'm just missing something with respect to how these MIDI devices work.

Comment: Your issue is more about the precise protocol for operating the LaunchPad MK3 than it is with MIDI or the library you're using to send/receive MIDI. As described this sounds like a MK3 bug, so check that you have the latest firmware installed. Otherwise, look for MK3 support or forum rather a general MIDI category.

Comment: RtMidi.Core is not the same as the coremidi tag which is a tag for the coremidi audio apis on Mac OS. REmoved the coremidi tag.

As for your question, the Mk3 controller has a native/classic mode and a midi controller mode and you didn't state which you are using.